# How do you get a list of the skins installed for a custom module in Dot Net Nuke

Tags: stored-procedures, frameworks, dotnetnuke

I am currently working on a custom module for Dot Net Nuke 7.2.2 and have run into a road bump. I need to be able to get a list of the installed skins for a drop down list, just as it appears in the Page Appearance page. I can't seem to find the Stored procedure that gets this info, or the Endpoint in the DotNetNuke framework to get this either. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all installed skin packages  from SQL table "SkinPackages".For Skin controls see the table "Skins".
If you are looking for inbuilt DNN store procedure then check GetSkinControl,GetSkinControlByKey,GetSkinPackage,GetSkinControlByPackageID and GetSkinPackage depending upon you requirement.